# Can't open any AppImage on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, appimage

I can't seem to open any AppImages at all. 
I get the *"No such file or directory"* error which seems odd.

The permissions should be correct too and a fresly downloaded AppImage won't launch either. Got any clue what this might cause?
[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**
I've tried it again with a suggested Appimage from the comments but alas, it doesn't work. This atleast explains that the issue lies in my system and not the AppImages.

Here is the code from the latest test:

```
massigest@Laptop-Massi:~/Applications/Leafpad$ ls -l
total 768
-rwxrwxr-x 1 massigest massigest 786432 mei 22 15:28 Leafpad-0.8.17-x86_64.AppImage
massigest@Laptop-Massi:~/Applications/Leafpad$ ./Leafpad-0.8.17-x86_64.AppImage 
bash: ./Leafpad-0.8.17-x86_64.AppImage: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE 2:**
NOTE: AppImage can't run in any directory. And the Applications folder is owned by me.

Other non AppImage applications can run in my applications folder, i've added an example of that below:

```
massigest@Laptop-Massi:~/Applications/ArduinoIDE$ ls -l arduino
-rwxrwxr-x 1 massigest massigest 882 dec  6 11:24 arduino
massigest@Laptop-Massi:~/Applications/ArduinoIDE$ ./arduino
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
```

Someone also requested that is should note the output of `mount`, so see that below here:

```
massigest@Laptop-Massi:~/Applications$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8121196k,nr_inodes=2030299,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1629296k,mode=755)
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1236)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-characters_206.snap on /snap/gnome-characters/206 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1122.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/discord_91.snap on /snap/discord/91 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-26-1604_82.snap on /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-logs_45.snap on /snap/gnome-logs/45 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/docker_384.snap on /snap/docker/384 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/spotify_32.snap on /snap/spotify/32 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6964.snap on /snap/core/6964 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/spotify_34.snap on /snap/spotify/34 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_941.snap on /snap/core18/941 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/mailspring_326.snap on /snap/mailspring/326 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/docker_381.snap on /snap/docker/381 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-26-1604_78.snap on /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6673.snap on /snap/core/6673 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6818.snap on /snap/core/6818 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_40.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/40 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium-ffmpeg_11.snap on /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/11 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium-ffmpeg_13.snap on /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/13 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/discord_92.snap on /snap/discord/92 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-characters_254.snap on /snap/gnome-characters/254 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/mailspring_346.snap on /snap/mailspring/346 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_782.snap on /snap/core18/782 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-logs_57.snap on /snap/gnome-logs/57 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-characters_258.snap on /snap/gnome-characters/258 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/datagrip_48.snap on /snap/datagrip/48 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/spotify_35.snap on /snap/spotify/35 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/whatsdesk_15.snap on /snap/whatsdesk/15 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1198.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_31.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/31 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/code_7.snap on /snap/code/7 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/docker_372.snap on /snap/docker/372 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-26-1604_74.snap on /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_970.snap on /snap/core18/970 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_818.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/818 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/discord_93.snap on /snap/discord/93 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_36.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/36 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/mailspring_338.snap on /snap/mailspring/338 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-logs_61.snap on /snap/gnome-logs/61 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/whatsdesk_17.snap on /snap/whatsdesk/17 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_770.snap on /snap/vlc/770 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium-ffmpeg_9.snap on /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/9 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb2 on /mnt/HardDisk type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,x-gvfs-show)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1629296k,mode=755)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/docker.mnt type nsfs (rw)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1629296k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/fuse on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/mailspring.mnt type nsfs (rw)
```

#### **UPDATE 3:**

I ran another command to check if my folder was owned by root. I can't post all of the output because of the character limit, but ill show the important results below:

```
  3018208     48 -rwxrwxr-x   1 root     root        47231 feb 28 12:35 ./Applications/lpass/lastpass-cli/build/Makefile
   524793      8 -rwxrwxr-x   1 root     root         5694 apr  8 10:27 ./Applications/appeditor-master/build/po/fr.gmo
```

You can also check out the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/nKmF0sPn) for the full output.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94049/discussion-on-question-by-massi-gest-cant-open-any-appimage-on-ubuntu-19-04).